# Mostrar un dato concreto de un array asociativo

Tags: php, array

Una pregunta sobre manejo de arrays en PHP.

Tengo este array:

```
$curso = array(
"DAW" => array(
                "1º SI" => array("horas" => 230, "plazas" => 30),
                "1º BD" => array("horas" => 200, "plazas" => 30),
                "1º PROG" => array("horas" => 260, "plazas" => 30),
                "1º ED" => array("horas" => 70, "plazas" => 30),
                "1º LMSGI" => array("horas" => 130, "plazas" => 30),
                "1º FOL" => array("horas" => 90, "plazas" => 30),

                "2º DIW" => array("horas" => 95, "plazas" => 30),
                "2º DWES" => array("horas" => 170, "plazas" => 30),
                "2º DWEC" => array("horas" => 170, "plazas" => 30),
                "2º DAW" => array("horas" => 75, "plazas" => 30),
                "2º EIE" => array("horas" => 60, "plazas" => 30),
                "2º FCT" => array("horas" => 410, "plazas" => 30),
                "2º PROYC" => array("horas" => 50, "plazas" => 30),                  
              ),

"DAM" =>array(
                "1º SI" => array("horas" => 230, "plazas" => 30),
                "1º BD" => array("horas" => 200, "plazas" => 30),
                "1º PROG" => array("horas" => 260, "plazas" => 30),
                "1º ED" => array("horas" => 70, "plazas" => 30),
                "1º LMSGI" => array("horas" => 130, "plazas" => 30),
                "1º FOL" => array("horas" => 90, "plazas" => 30),

                "2º PMD"=> array("horas"=>155, "plazas"=>30),
                "2º PSP"=> array("horas"=>155, "plazas"=>30),
                "2º SGE"=> array("horas"=>55, "plazas"=>30),
                "2º AD"=> array("horas"=>95, "plazas"=>30),
                "2º DI"=> array("horas"=>95, "plazas"=>30),
                "2º FCT"=> array("horas"=>60, "plazas"=>30),
                "2º FCT"=> array("horas"=>410, "plazas"=>30),
                "2º PROYC"=> array("horas"=>55, "plazas"=>30),

             ),

"ASIR" => array(
                "1º ISO" => array("horas" => 230, "plazas" =>30),
                "1º PAR" => array("horas" => 150, "plazas" =>30),
                "1º FH" => array("horas" => 110, "plazas" =>30),
                "1º GBD" => array("horas" => 230, "plazas" =>30),
                "1º LMSGI" => array("horas" => 140, "plazas" =>30),
                "1º FOL" => array("horas" => 90, "plazas" =>30),

                "2º ASO" => array("horas" => 135, "plazas" =>30),
                "2º SRI" => array("horas" => 170, "plazas" =>30),
                "2º IAW" => array("horas" => 170, "plazas" =>30),
                "2º ASGBD" => array("horas" => 75, "plazas" =>30),
                "2º SAD" => array("horas" => 60, "plazas" =>30),
                "2º EIE" => array("horas" => 30, "plazas" =>30),
                "2º FCT" => array("horas" => 410, "plazas" =>30),

            ));
```

Quiero mostrar los datos solo del array "ASIR" y solo de este osea quiero mostrar:

```
                "1º PAR" 
                "1º FH" 
                "1º GBD" 
                "1º LMSGI" 
                "1º FOL"
```

Me he aproximado haciendo esto:

```
 <?php
                $mostrarModulos = "";
                foreach ($curso as $ciclos => $modulos) {

                    echo $ciclos;
                    foreach ($modulos as $modulo => $dato) {
                        $mostrarModulos .= "<label for='modulos'>'$modulo'</label><input type='checkbox' id='modulos' name='$modulo'><br>";
                        echo $mostrarModulos;
                    }
                }

                echo $curso["DAW"];
                ?>
```

Pero claro esto me muestra lo de todos los módulos y yo solo quiero que me muestre uno en concreto.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es fácil simplemente utiliza el foreach pasando esa parte del array.

**Ejemplo**

```
foreach ($curso['ASIR'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.', HORAS: '.$value['horas'].' PLAZAS: '.$value['plazas'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Resultado:

```
1º ISO, HORAS: 230 PLAZAS: 30
1º PAR, HORAS: 150 PLAZAS: 30
1º FH, HORAS: 110 PLAZAS: 30
1º GBD, HORAS: 230 PLAZAS: 30
1º LMSGI, HORAS: 140 PLAZAS: 30
1º FOL, HORAS: 90 PLAZAS: 30
2º ASO, HORAS: 135 PLAZAS: 30
2º SRI, HORAS: 170 PLAZAS: 30
2º IAW, HORAS: 170 PLAZAS: 30
2º ASGBD, HORAS: 75 PLAZAS: 30
2º SAD, HORAS: 60 PLAZAS: 30
2º EIE, HORAS: 30 PLAZAS: 30
2º FCT, HORAS: 410 PLAZAS: 30
```

Comment: Gracias Francisco era es lo que querìa. Me esta ofuscando. Otra pregunta.. Si solo quiero mostrar un dato. En plan quiero mostrar del array de "ASIR" el dato "1ºGBD"... pero solo ese dato y mostrarlo con un echo.

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion que encontre para mostrar los últimos datos de array fue a siguiente: (Teniendo en cuenta el array que usaba):

foreach ($_SESSION['seleccion'] as $modulo) {
    foreach ($curso['DAW'][$modulo] as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'horas') {
            $horasCiclo += $value;
            continue; //evito que me coga el otro valor del array
        }
    }
}